# pass php array to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Can someone please give me a simple example how should jquery $.ajax syntax look like in order to pass array from php to jquery.

On server side I have:

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5); 
echo json_encode($a);
```

So, I'd like get this to js and have:

```
   js_array=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

I'd really appreciate any help, cause I've been trying for some time now and no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: You should set a proper content type in the PHP code, like `header("Content-type: application/json");`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET', // or POST
  url: 'yourfile.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {}, // put data to be sent via GET/POST into this object if necessary
  success: function(response) {
    // response is your array
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was doing the same thing for two hours and didn't realize 2 things. First, it's "dataType" not "datatype" and second, I was echoing wrong format from php in the first plase.Soo...THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

you can either use:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    //do something with data
  }
});
```

or:

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
  do something with data
})
```